# Se crea como vacío nuevo POST

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Al crear un nuevo usuario con POST me dice que se ha creado correctamente , pero al comprobar con un GET todos mis usuarios , ese usuario se me ha creado como vacío {} . ¿A qué debe de ser?

```
app.get(BASE_API_PATH + "/contacts", (req, res) => {
    console.log(Date() + " - GET /contacts");

    db.find({}).toArray((err, contacts) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Error accesing DB");
            res.sendStatus(500);
            return;
        }

        res.send(contacts.map((c) => {
            delete c._id;
            return c;
        }));
    });

});

app.post(BASE_API_PATH + "/contacts", (req, res) => {
    console.log(Date() + " - POST /contacts");
    var contact = req.body;


    if (!contact) {
        console.log("warning : new Get req");
        res.sendStatus(400);
    }
    db.find({ "name": contact.name }).toArray((err, contacts) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("error accesing db");
            res.sendStatus(400);
        }
        if (contacts.length > 0) {
            console.log("warning");
            res.sendStatus(409);
        }
        else {
            db.insert(contact);
            res.sendStatus(201);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Estas usando MongoDB como base de datos?? si es que si que usas para conectarte a ella mongoose o algun otro paquete de nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Entendiendo que estas usando MongoDB y que 'db' esta relacionado con la misma base de datos y colección, haz probado en realizar esto:

```
app.get(BASE_API_PATH + "/contacts", (req, res) => {
console.log(Date() + " - GET /contacts");

  db.find({},{_id:0, name:1}).toArray((err, contacts) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Error accesing DB");
        res.sendStatus(500);
        return;
    }

    res.send(contacts);
  });
});
```

Aunque, también podría haber un error en el insert. Podrías mostrar como es el objeto 'contact' que se envía desde la petición POST